# Download clicks counter + Firebase Database

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-realtime-database

My code saves the value, more when the page is refreshed and clicks on the button the value back to the 1

```
var button = document.getElementById("button-download"),
    count = 0;

button.onclick = function() {
    count += 1;
    firebase.database().ref('counter').set(count);
    updateValue();
};

function updateValue() {
    firebase.database().ref('counter').once('value', function(snapshot) {
        var badge = document.getElementById("badge-value");
        badge.innerHTML = "Download: " + snapshot.val();
    });
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to ensure you first read the value, before then setting it to a new value. Firebase nowadays has a built-in increment operator to do that:

```
button.onclick = function() {
    firebase.database().ref('counter').set(firebase.database.ServerValue.increment(1));
};

firebase.database().ref('counter').on('value', function(snapshot) {
    var badge = document.getElementById("badge-value");
    badge.innerHTML = "Download: " + snapshot.val();
});
```

you'll note that I don't update (nor need) the local `count` nor refresh the UI in `onclick` anymore. That's because the code now listens to the database with `on()`, which ensures both of those happen automatically.